Could we convert lunar regolith into a trinitite landing pad with an atomic weapon?
My thinking here is that a modern thermonuclear weapon would not weigh very much and that by detonating one an appropriate distance above the lunar surface, the regolith could be melted into a hard flat surface for a lander to land on. Then the landers' landing gear mass could be reduced, lunar landings would be de-risked, the area immediately around the landing site would become a relatively dust-free environment, and utility vehicles could move around on regular wheels while unloading cargo and setting up a base. Overall, the strategy might result in a net payload mass saving for a program like Artemis.
The weapon would have to be detonated days or weeks before the landing attempt to give the molten regolith time to cool and harden.
I suspect that most of the nuclear fallout would fly off into deep space. Any that reached the moon would be dispersed widely, not creating a significant hazard. Is it possible that the pros of this idea could outweigh the cons?

https://www.reddit.com/r/astrophysics/comments/16hhulu/nuking_a_landing_spot_on_the_moon/

https://sites.google.com/view/sources-nukethemoon/

Why would landing on a hard surface be less risky or require less robust landing gear? If anything, I would think the force of impact with the ground would be higher the less it deforms.

The landing would be more predictable. With a regolith landing, you'd need the extra weight of engines mounted higher up on the craft plus larger pads to prevent the gear from sinking into the soft regolith. If you didn't add the engines up top, then you would be landing in a hole of your own making.

@Cadence consider that Falcon 9 lands on nicely prepared concrete pads (or drone ship) and not just a beach or field

@Cadence My impression is that the real benefit of a hard landing pad is that you don't blow dust everywhere with rockets. However, I must say I am skeptical of this scheme.

I am skeptical as to whether the brief, intense flash of radiation from a nuclear explosive would actually be an effective way to fuse a large amount of regolith into a cohesive mass. Meanwhile, using nuclear explosives for nearly any purpose is politically and legally problematic.

There at almost 10,000 operational nuclear weapons on Earth. I think we should send them all to the Moon. Finally: a sensible mission for Starship.

This answer is going to be more opinionated than I'd usually like an answer to be.  I don't know how avoidable that is--I'd expect an actual trade study on this to include a lot of seemingly-codified opinion too.  But here goes:
I believe the cons outweigh the pros.

Current lunar landing sensor systems (like the Navigation Doppler Lidar for Precise Velocity and Range Sensing that flew on IM-1 Odysseus) operate on assumptions about the lunar terrain that are invalidated by glassing it.  New test campaigns would have to be conducted to test sensors for the initial landing.

The inclusion of a nuclear weapon militarizes the mission. NASA isn't going to be allowed to have one without supervision.  This will change a LOT, from astronaut selection to the international nature of the Artemis missions to tacking on an enormous extra layer of Department of Defense bureaucracy to things.

this arguably constitutes a violation of several Outer Space Treaty provisions, including (quoting from the Wikipedia article)


States shall not place nuclear weapons or other weapons of mass destruction in orbit or on celestial bodies or station them in outer space in any other manner;
the Moon and other celestial bodies shall be used exclusively for peaceful purposes; prohibits their use for testing weapons of any kind, conducting military maneuvers, or establishing military bases, installations, and fortifications

...

States shall avoid harmful contamination of space and celestial bodies.
All the following regarding the detonation of the weapon may be subject to tuning parameters (height of detonation, yield of weapon, etc). I'm assuming that the goal state is even possible.



The detonation of a nuclear weapon may compromise lunar science objectives in the vicinity of the detonation; I'm thinking particularly of geology, but the ongoing consequences may be open-ended.  Bits of bomb might shoot straight through Tranquility base to the eternal annoyance of future space-archaeologists, who knows.

The detonation of a nuclear weapon may compromise the usable resources in the vicinity of the detonation, or at least complicate their utilization. For example, now you have nuclear fallout contaminating ice you would otherwise use for potable water.

The detonation of a nuclear weapon will compromise political support for the Artemis missions, particularly in the US, endangering much of the program's funding. "Nuclear" is a poison word in American culture, so much so that there was controversy about using RTGs. That would be enhanced with this actually being a nuclear weapon, despite it being a more utilitarian use than the nominal one.


And maybe the most-opinion of all:

Exploration programs should include landings on unprepared terrain. In such a precedent-driven ("well that's how Shuttle did it") industry, it's better for the future of all our exploration sites to not normalize detonating nuclear weapons on them when we first visit.  Depending on who you ask, part of the point of visiting the moon at all is to have a nearby opportunity to train for our future space endeavors. Better to train in the more-universally-applicable "don't nuke this" mode.


Another reason not to: It doesn't result in a flat surface anyway. See Figure 6.06 https://atomicarchive.com/resources/documents/effects/glasstone-dolan/chapter6.html

@OrganicMarble It's wasn't clear to me those figures are applicable to detonation above a surface in a near-vacuum, but I'm inclined to believe it based on the sources link Alan Birtles left for this video. However, since the question leaves wiggle-room in how the weapon is applied, I personally find it preferable to assume that it works perfectly but that even then the balance seem overwhelmingly con.
